# How to edit misc/print.css without changing core

Tags: theming, 8

I want to edit core/misc/print.css that the Book module is referencing, and I don't know how.

If I should move the print.css somewhere and load a new print.css in my theme.info, or is there another way make changes to the core/misc/print.css without changing core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to edit any core file, to achieve what you are trying to do. Since you are talking of a theme, you just need to replace the template file used from the Book module. This is what done from the Stable theme, which has its own [book-export-html.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21stable%21templates%21layout%21book-export-html.html.twig/8.2.x).

The only reference to the misc/print.css file is in [book-export-html.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21book%21templates%21book-export-html.html.twig/8.2.x); there isn't any core library with a reference to that file, and this makes things easier for a theme.
[book-export-html.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21book%21templates%21book-export-html.html.twig/8.2.x) contains the following code.

```
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    {{ page.head }}
    <base href="{{ base_url }}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="misc/print.css" />
  </head>
```

In the template file for your theme, you just replace it with the following, if you don't want to use any print.css file.

```
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    {{ page.head }}
    <base href="{{ base_url }}" />
  </head>
```

If you just need to use a different print.css file for your theme, then you can simply edit the file path, and provide your own CSS file.

```
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    {{ page.head }}
    <base href="{{ base_url }}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="the_path_relative_to_the_theme_folder/print.css" />
  </head>
```

Comment: Yes, the whole html page including `<head>` is in one twig template, because the Book module bypasses the drupal theming level and returns the printed output directly in a response: `return new Response($this->renderer->renderRoot($exported_book));`